# Rearrange Formula with Division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone please help explain to me how I would solve this formula to get 'C1'?

$2000 = \frac{1.44}{1000+(2*47000)*C1}$

---

*What I understand*:

I understand rearranging formula with fractions when they are basic ones like:
$x= \frac{a}{b}$ where you would multiply by 'b' and divide by 'x' giving you : $b= \frac{a}{x}$

*How I struggle:*

But I do not understand how to do that in a situation like this.  If you divide by C1  you would get $\frac{2000}{C1}$ on one side but then how does the division work? Would you divide by 2000? and would that divide the whole other side by 2000? such as: $C1= \frac{(\frac{1.44}{1000+(2*47000)})}{2000}$

I also saw on a tutorial that you can swap the sides and make it: $1000+(2*47000)*C1= \frac{1.44}{2000}$ but I am still stuck on how to continue to divide when there is already division.

Any explination or better methods to solve this would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Multiply both sides by the whole denominator on the right.  That will clear the fraction.  Now you have a linear equation.

Comment: Would that mean make it 1.44/95,000*C1? and then multiply both by 95,000? making it: 2000*(95,000*C1) = 1.44?  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: No, the right side becomes $1.44$  The left becomes $2000\cdot (1000+2\cdot 47000\cdot C_1)$.  I said the whole denominator.

Comment: Ok thank you, would you mind explaining how to solve for that?  Would it become: 22000*(1000+94,000*C1)? how do you move forward here?

Comment: Now you just unpack the $C_1$.  You can divide both sides by $2000$ (not $22000$), then subtract $1000$, then divide by $94000$

Answer (score 2):

Let $2000 = \frac{1.44}{(2*47000)C_1)}$. We can rewrite the fraction with whole numbers rather than decimals to make it simpler, therefore: $\frac{1.44}{2 * 47000C_1 + 1000} = \frac{36}{25(94000C_1 + 1000)}$.

Re-substitute and take the reciprocal we should get:

$2000 = \frac{36}{25(94000C_1 + 1000)} \implies \frac{1}{2000} = \frac{25}{36}(94000C_1 + 1000)$.

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{36}{25}$ gives us $94000C_1 + 1000 = \frac{9}{12500}$ and subtracting by $1000$ and dividing both sides by $94000$ should give you:

$C_1 = -\frac{
12499991}{1175000000} \approx -0.01$

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explination and you definitely found the answer to solve for C.  unfortunately I think your process may be above my level.  I didn't understand how you got  36/25(94000C1+1000) in your first step and therefore I couldnt follow after.